# ¿En una matriz de tipo String, como puedo ordenar las filas de esa matriz según las puntuaciones que hay en columna?

Tags: java, matrices, cast

- Estoy diseñando un menú de opciones, en la opción 2 y 3 tengo que ordenar las filas matriz según la puntuación que tiene cada jugador, por ejemplo si el jugador de la fila 1 tiene 20 puntos en la columna 0 y el jugador de la fila 2 tiene 30 puntos en la columna 0 necesitó que el jugador que tiene más puntos pase a la primera fila.
- He creado 2 bucles tipo for para esto, pero cuando intento ordenar las columnas en las que se almacena el dorsal o las puntuaciones, no me deja entrar en los if porque tipo string no puede ser convertido a entero.
- Utilice el método compareTO y también utilice el metodo integer. value of para hacer un cast de entero a string y no sale nada.
- Para cambiar las filas de la matriz creo un array que almacena 1 fila y luego las cambio pero no se me ejecuta el código.
- el problema está en la opción 3 del menú (case 3 del primer switch).
- se intenta ordenar las filas de la matriz por las marcas obtenidas en el 2020.
- El código se podria optimizar pero aun necesito que funcione.

- 1. Se pretende realizar un programa para gestionar la lista de participaciones en una competición de salto de longitud.
- 2. El número de plazas disponible es de 5.
- 3. Sus datos se irán introduciendo en el mismo orden que vayan inscribiéndose los atletas.
- 4. Si se selecciona 1, se introducirán los datos de uno de los participantes:
- ```
   - Dorsal, Nombre, mejor marca del 2018, mejor marca del 2019 y mejor marca del 2020.
  ```
- ```
   - Si se elige la opción 2, se debe mostrar un listado por número de dorsal.
  ```
- ```
   - La opción 3 mostrará un listado ordenado por la marca del 2020, de mayor a menor.
  ```
- 5. Tras procesar cada opción, se debe mostrar de nuevo el menú inicial, hasta que se seleccione la opción 4, que terminará el programa.
- 6. Diseñar el programa que muestre las siguientes opciones:
- ```
   - Inscribir un participante.
  ```
- ```
   - Mostrar listado de datos.
  ```
- ```
   - Mostrar listado por marcas.
  ```
- ```
   - Finalizar el programa.
  ```

Adjunto codigo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class perezSuarezCristoRuben_Actividad_1_055 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*
         *  - La matriz va a tener 5 filas que equivalen a la cantidad de participantes máxima.
         *  - La matriz tendrá 5 columnas porque es la cantidad de datos mínima y máxima a almacenar.
         */
        String [][] datosParticipantes = new String [5][5];

        // Esta variable almacenará los datos de cada usuario y los ira trasladando a las posiciones correspondientes de la matriz según la toma de requisitos.
        String datos = "";

        // Esta variable controlara que opción del menú del programa se ejecutara.
        int opcionMenu = 0;

        /*
         *  - Si el usuario presiona 4 el valor de la variable cambiara de false a true.
         *  - El bucle while dejara de ejecutar las instrucciones por lo cual el programa dejara de ejecutarse.
         */
        boolean cerrarPrograma = false;

        // Esta variable ira sumando 1 cada vez que se introduzca un usuario para controlar que filas y columnas de la matriz se rellenan.
        int contadorUsuarios = 1;

        /*
         *  - Este bucle controlara la condición de salida del programa que dependiendo de si el usuario pulsa un 4 saldrá del menú o no y finalizara el programa.
         *  - Será de tipo while porque no sabemos cuando el usuario quiere terminar el proceso.
         */
        while (cerrarPrograma == false) {

            // Este bucle controlará que la variable está dentro de los rangos de las opciones para evitar errores futuros en la ejecución del programa.
            do {

                // Indicamos las opciones disponibles y pedimos que introduzca una.
                System.out.println("- Pulse 1 para añadir un participante.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 2 para ver el listado de participante y el dorsal que les corresponde.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 3 para ver un listado ordenado de la marca obtenida por los participantes en el 2020 / 2019 / 2018.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 4 para cerrar el programa.");
                   opcionMenu = sc.nextInt();

                    // Aquí tengo que vaciar el buffer porque me estaba dado errores en la impresión de mensajes.
                    sc.nextLine();

                // Espacio entre el menú de opciones y la entrada / salida de datos.
                System.out.println("");

            } while (opcionMenu < 1 && opcionMenu > 4);
            
            switch (opcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                    switch (contadorUsuarios) {
                        case 1:

                            for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++)    {

                                if (i == 0) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del primer participante:");
                                }

                                if (i == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del primer participante:");
                                }

                                if (i == 2) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del primer participante:");
                                }

                                if (i == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del primer participante:");
                                }

                                if (i == 4) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del primer participante:");
                                }

                                datos = sc.nextLine();
                                datosParticipantes [0][i] = datos;

                            }

                            contadorUsuarios += 1;

                            break;

                        case 2:

                            for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length; j++)    {

                                if (j == 0) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del segundo participante:");
                                }

                                if (j == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del segundo participante:");
                                }

                                if (j == 2) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del segundo participante:");
                                }

                                if (j == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del segundo participante:");
                                }

                                if (j == 4) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del segundo participante:");
                                }

                                datos = sc.nextLine();
                                datosParticipantes [1][j] = datos;

                            }

                            contadorUsuarios += 1;

                            break;

                        case 3:

                            for (int j2 = 0; j2 < datosParticipantes.length; j2++) {
                                if (j2 == 0) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del tercer participante:");
                                }

                                if (j2 == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del tercer participante:");
                                }

                                if (j2 == 2) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del tercer participante:");
                                }

                                if (j2 == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del tercer participante:");
                                }

                                if (j2 == 4) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del tercer participante:");
                                }

                                datos = sc.nextLine();
                                datosParticipantes [2][j2] = datos;
                                
                            }

                            contadorUsuarios += 1;

                            break;

                        case 4:

                            for (int k = 0; k < datosParticipantes.length; k++)    {
                                if (k == 0) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del cuarto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del cuarto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k == 2) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del cuarto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del cuarto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k == 4) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del cuarto participante:");
                                }

                                datos = sc.nextLine();
                                datosParticipantes [3][k] = datos;
                                
                            }

                            contadorUsuarios += 1;

                            break;

                        case 5:

                            for (int k2 = 0; k2 < datosParticipantes.length; k2++) {

                                if (k2 == 0) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del quinto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k2 == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del quinto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k2 == 2) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del quinto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k2 == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del quinto participante:");
                                }

                                if (k2 == 4) {
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del quinto participante:");
                                }

                                datos = sc.nextLine();
                                datosParticipantes [4][k2] = datos;                              

                            }

                            contadorUsuarios += 1;

                            // Para dejar un espacio entre el case 5 y case 6.
                            System.out.println("");

                            break;
                        
                        /*
                         *  Si se han introducido 5 usuarios el contador habrá llegado a 6 y indicará que no se puede introducir más usuarios.
                         */
                        case 6:

                            System.out.println("~ La competición solo dispone de 5 plazas no se pueden introducir más usuarios.");

                            break;
                    
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:

                    // Los bucles for empiezan en 0 al igual que las posiciones de las matrices para indicar el número de participantes en una impresión de datos necesitó una variable que empiece en 1.
                    int aux;

                    // La toma de requisitos exige que se imprima un listado de los dorsales, pero no que estén ordenados así que imprimiré los dorsales por el orden de participantes ingresados.
                    for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {

                        aux = i + 1;

                        System.out.println("Al participante número " + aux + " con nombre " + datosParticipantes [i][1] + " le corresponde el dorsal número " + datosParticipantes [i][0] + ".");
                        
                    }

                    // Espacio entre el menú de opciones y la entrada / salida de datos.
                    System.out.println("");

                    break;

                case 3:
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length - i - 1; j++) {
                            
                            int pepa1 = Integer.valueOf(datosParticipantes[j][0]);
                            int pepa2 = Integer.valueOf(datosParticipantes[j+1][0]);

                            if (pepa1 < pepa2) {
                                // Intercambia 2 filas de la matriz.
                                string[] aux2 = datosParticipantes[j];
                                datosParticipantes[j] = datosParticipantes[j+1];
                                datosParticipantes[j+1] = aux2;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length; j++) {
                            System.out.println(datosParticipantes[i][j]);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                    
                case 4:

                    // Aquí tengo que vaciar el buffer porque me estaba dado errores en la impresión de mensajes.
                    sc.nextLine();

                    cerrarPrograma = true;

                    break;
            
                default:
                    break;
            }

            // Para dejar un espacio entre el menú de opciones y la salida de mensajes.
            System.out.println("");

        }     
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que debes comparar los datos del 2020 de los 5 participantes no solo de dos.
para ello puedes guardar solo esos valores en un array y mediante un método de ordenación, obtener  los valores ingresados de mayor a menor, luego mediante el uso de `equals()` debido a que tu matriz es de tipo `String` comparas los valores obteniendo el índice de los valores en la matriz `datosParticipante` y asi mediante una nueva matriz guardar los valores en su nuevo orden.

```
System.out.println("Lista de Participantes por Marcas");
System.out.println("=================================\n");

         int [] datos2020=new int[5];
         String [][] matrizOrdenada=new String [5][5];
         int []aux=new int[5];
         int w=0;
         int x=0;
        //obtienes los datos del 2020
         for (int z=0;z<5;z++){
           datos2020[z]=Integer.parseInt(datos[z][4]);  
         }  
         //ordenas los datos de Menor a Mayor usando sort      
         Arrays.sort(datos2020);
         //obtienes los valores de Mayor a Menor usando un for descendente
         for (int z=4;z>-1;z--) {
            aux[w]=datos2020[z];
            w++;
         }
         //Mediante los indices pasas los datos a una nueva Matriz       
         for (int z=0;z<datos.length;z++) {
            for(int y=0;y<datos.length;y++){
               if(datos[y][4].equals(String.valueOf(aux[z]))){
                   matrizOrdenada[x]=datos[y];
               }
             }
             x++;
          }
         //Imprimes la matriz ordenada
        String fmt = "%1$8s%2$8s%3$8s%4$8s%5$8s%n";
        System.out.printf(fmt,"Dorsal","Nombre","2018","2019","2020");
        System.out.println("");

         for (int k=0;k<matrizOrdenada.length;k++ ) {
            for (int l=0;l<matrizOrdenada[k].length;l++ ) {
                System.out.printf("%1$8s",matrizOrdenada[k][l]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }
```

psdta: tu solicitud de ingreso de datos es algo que se repite 5 veces usar un bucle para ello te ahorraria varias lineas de codigo ;)